# How to check if the CD data is uploaded to CDDB?

Tags: software

So I got some pressed CDs and they had the problem with "fuzzy recognition", which is quite common. I followed this guide: http://support.gracenote.com/articles/Public_FAQ/Submit-CD-iTunes-12/?l=en_US&c=Public%3AArtists_Labels_Publishers&cu=1&fs=ContactUs&pn=1

So I did all the steps except I didn't include the number of discs I currently have, because I might press more. They say it takes up to 2 days to upload info to CDDB. Is there a way to check if my CD data has been successfully uploaded and what actions should I do if my data wasn't uploaded correctly?

Comment: Does this help? http://support.gracenote.com/articles/Public_FAQ/What-if-my-CD-still-doesn-t-show-up/?l=en_US&c=Public%3AArtists_Labels_Publishers&cu=1&fs=ContactUs&pn=3

Comment: @b3ko Probably will. I'll check tomorrow.